# How do I pass URLs from my Django rest API to the Flutter front-end

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

I am very new to the Django REST framework and Flutter so if the solution to this is very simple I apologize.

I am trying to pass the URLs from my Django back-end to the Flutter front-end. I feel like the solution is a `urls.dart` file where I can store all the URLs from Django.

However, I have no idea what the code for this file would look like.
Here are the URLs that I need to be passed over

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes),
    path('notes/',views.getNotes),
    path('notes/create/', views.createNote),
    path('notes/<str:pk>/update/', views.updateNote),
    path('notes/<str:pk>/delete/', views.deleteNote),
    path('notes/<str:pk>/',views.getNote),
]
```

It is not deployed so I am using localhost.

When I implement the URLs into the flutter code I want them to look something like this:

```dart
.put(updateUrl(widget.id), body: {'body': controller.text});

widget.client.post(createUrl, body: {'body': controller.text});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To send requests and receive a response did you try using **http** or **dio** packages for flutter?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31412966)